# Update , Delete and Edit Table on MS SQL Server with different errors

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a table called "News-News" that can save my website's news in it.
I add new four columns to this table with "int" and "nvarchar(3999)" data types.
The problem is here: I can change data type's to "nvarchar(50)" and I can save it successfully but when I want to change it to "nvarchar(3999)" again, It returns this error:

```
'News-News' table- Unable to modify table.  Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

The problem isn't finished yet! I can insert data to this table but I cant delete and Update it.
This is error:

```
string or binary data would be truncated
The data in row 1 was not committed
.Net SqlClient Data Provider
```

This is the table full code :

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[News-News]  ******/

    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](399) NOT NULL,
    [Abstract] [ntext] NULL,
    [Value] [ntext] NULL,
    [UserID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [GroupID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Date] [nvarchar](3999) NOT NULL,
    [Views] [int] NULL,
    [Hates] [int] NULL,
    [Likes] [int] NULL,
    [Source] [nvarchar](3999) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_News-News] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Columns of Hates , Likes , Views , and Source are new.

I have this problem on MS SQL Management Studio and my ASP.NET website. Both have same timeout problem.

---

**UPDATE**
I have a SqlDataSource called "NewsSqlDataSource" that has three queries for "Insert" , "Update" , and "Delete".
I use `NewsSqlDataSource.Insert();` for inserting,  `NewsSqlDataSource.Update();` for editing, and `NewsSqlDataSource.Delete();` for deleting.
Here I have query codes:

- For inserting

`INSERT INTO [News-News] (Title, Abstract, Value, UserID, GroupID, Date, Source) VALUES (@title, @Abstract, @Value, @UserID, @GroupID, @Date, @Source)`

- For Updating

`UPDATE [News-News] SET Title = @Title, Abstract = @Abstract, Value = @Value, Date = @Date, GroupID = @GroupID, Source = @Source WHERE (ID = @ID)`

- For Deleting

`DELETE FROM [News-News] WHERE (ID = @ID)`

Comment: This question seems a better fit for [DBA StackExchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/). Consider deleting this question and posting it on that site instead.

Comment: You have a table so you can not create it again! Your code shows you are going to create `News-News` table again.

Comment: That code want's to show you the database columns and data types. I know that it uses in CREATE command of SQL Server. My questions are about errors. * First error of changing table columns in design mode and Second is about Updating and Deleting data in row.

Comment: You didn't show the script you used to alter that table. Please post that.

Answer (score 5):

You can't insert the data because the data that you're trying to insert is too wide for the column and [`ANSI_WARNINGS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190368%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) is `ON`. Given the content of your application, you probably don't want to turn it `OFF` and let the server silently truncate the data.

The other error that you're getting is *probably* due to the fact that your table is getting large and the SQL Server is consuming too many resources because it's essentially storing the data in work table and then updating the original table all with temp objects and RAM.

Here's what I'd do.

```
SELECT 
    [ID],
    [Title],
    [Abstract],
    [Value],
    [UserID],
    [GroupID],
    [Date],
    [Views],
    [Hates],
    [Likes],
    [Source]
INTO dbo.[News-News_Newest]
FROM [dbo].[News-News];

DROP TABLE [dbo].[News-News_Newest];
GO

EXEC sp_rename '[News-News_Newest]' , '[News-News]';
GO

ALTER TABLE [News-News]
  ADD CONSTRAINT PK_News_ID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID ASC);
```

Please note that you will need to figure out how to handle any foreign keys if they exist. You'll also need to make sure no writes will occur on this table while you're doing this.

Comment: I can insert data into database but I can't Update and Delete it. I Told it in my question to.

Comment: Let me see. First you send data to new table called "News-News_Newest" and after that you renamed it to "News-News". If I right , this is not fast solution for my problem. Here's another question: Why I cant update data of a specific row in my Table?

Comment: @MohammadRezaTayyebi I thought I addressed that. You've inserted existing data that met the original requirements. Now you need wider data or ANSI_WARNINGS was originally set to OFF. I'm assuming you're trying to update the existing table with data that is wider than you've defined so you're getting an error. Is this on a new server?

Comment: @MohammadRezaTayyebi the speed of the process will depend on your data, your server specs, and other activity on the server. Also, it'll be faster than what you're currently doing: `Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.`

Comment: I think it's better to know that this problem is same between "ASP.NET" and "SQL Server Management Studio (Design time)" and also similar between my server and "(LocalDb)\v11.0"

Comment: So you ***are*** doing this between two database instances.

Comment: No, But I tried this on server and local. [This](http://www.snowcity.ir/News) is the website that uses the database. You can translate it on translate.Google.com

Comment: What do the famous websites (Like yahoo! and twitter) do? I want to change my website to real News Application.

Comment: Considering your answer and comments, I tried many ways to delete data with following code:`DELETE FROM [News-News] WHERE (ID=1)`. This code can execute successfully on MS SQL Server Management Studio but when I use it in asp.net, I have timeout error again.

Answer (score 2):

I just saw that you used the design mode of SSMS to change the table. This is a mistake and tables should **never** be altered this way if they have significant amounts of data in them. Personally I feel you shouldn't ever use the designer because the code should be in a script in source control so you can move it to production from dev easily. Alter table is typically much faster than using the designer which loads all the data to a temp table and then makes the change and then loads the database. If you have a lot of data, then you will have a problem with timeouts using the designer.

Comment: Do you want to call this a bug? bug for SQL Server management studio designer?

Comment: No it is not a bug, it is intentional design to prevent you from accidentally losing data. The assumption is that anyone using the designer doesn't know what they are doing and so should be prevented from an accidendtal data loss or is creating a table for a prototype. It is not intended for use by a developer to work with populated tables.  If you are using it for actual development you are doing things incorrectly. All tables should be designed using sql scripts stored in source control like other code.

Comment: Considering your answer and comments, I tried many ways to delete data with following code:`DELETE FROM [News-News] WHERE (ID=1)`. This code can execute successfully on MS SQL Server Management Studio but when I use it in asp.net, I have timeout error again.